# Can't use function from a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a dictionary with a function as a value, but

```
NameError: name 'oak' is not defined
```

stops the execution before showing anything else.

This is the class with the dispatcher:

```
from hab_oak import Oak
from pokemon import Pokemon
from hab_brock import GimnasioBrock

class Juego(object):

    habs = {
        'Oak' : oak  
    }

    def __init__(self):
        oak = Oak()
        maproom, pok = oak.execution()
        self.Pokemon = pok
        dispatcher(Juego.habs.get(maproom), self.Pokemon)


    def dispatcher(command, arg):
        send(habs[command](arg))


    def oak(self, pokemon):
        GimnasioBrock(pokemon)
```

I'm pretty sure this next class Oak isn't the one giving the error, but it's the one being instantiated in Juego.**init**

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint
from pokemon import Pokemon
from hab_brock import GimnasioBrock

class Oak(object):

    def execution(self):
        print "Bienvenido, soy Oak. Elige un pokemon."
        print "Puedes elegir Charmander, Squirtle o Bulbasaur:"

        pokemon_elegido = raw_input("> ")

        if (pokemon_elegido == "Charmander"):
            pokemon = Pokemon("Charmander", 20, 5)
        elif (pokemon_elegido == "Bulbasaur"):
            pokemon = Pokemon("Bulbasaur", 20, 5)
        elif(pokemon_elegido == "Squirtle"):
            pokemon = Pokemon("Squirtle", 20, 5)

        print "Te enfrentaras a Brock."

        return "Oak", pokemon
```

Comment: You're using the dict as a [class variable, not an instance variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), so `oak` is not defined when it is evaluated.

Comment: It's very confusing to have "oak" and "Oak" both in this program

Comment: `NameError`, gotta catch em all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the dictionary value to the function before the function has been defined by the class. If you want to store the function in the class variable either change `oak()` to a static method or set the function as a value in the `__init__()`

Static Method Example:

```
class Juego(object):

    habs = {
        'Oak' : Juego.oak()  
    }

    @staticmethod
    def oak(pokemon):
        GimnasioBrock(pokemon)
```

Init Example:

```
class Juego(object):

    habs = {}

    def __init__(self):
        oak = Oak()
        maproom, pok = oak.execution()
        self.Pokemon = pok
        dispatcher(Juego.habitaciones.get(maproom), self.Pokemon)
        self.habs.update({'Oak':self.oak})

    def oak(self, pokemon):
        GimnasioBrock(pokemon)
```